# Is there any advantage of Simple Hashing over Consistent Hashing?

Tags: hash, hashtable, dht, consistent-hashing

Can anyone possible let me know any advantages of Simple Hashing over Consistent Hashing. I was looking over internet and couldn't found some parameters like time to add a new node in consistent Hashing vs Simple Hashing or time to retrieve a key from Consistent Hashing over Simple Hashing. Any Help would be good.

Comment: Counterquestion: In which context do you want to use consistent hashing and on which metrics do you think it would perform better?

Comment: I think consistent is only used in P2P Networks for sharing some info.